# What is the optimal way to track stats in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a Ruby on Rails app that is a game of sorts. There is a User model where each user has about 10 attributes, and each attribute has about 10 possible values. Users rate other users with a pass or fail boolean. I want to keep track of stats for every time a user is rated pass. So a tally for each user of the attributes of who they passed, and the attributes of who rated them as a pass. And I want a stats page where a user can see each of the 10 attributes and a count for each attribute value of who they passed and who passed them.

What I have come up with is a model called Stat with a belongs_to/has_one association with user.

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_one :stat

# app/models/stat.rb
belongs_to :user
```

The stats table has a row for each user and a user_id field. Then it has integer fields for each of the 10 possible choices for each of the user's 10 attributes (so 100 fields) for both when the user is rater and when the user is ratee (so 100 x 2). That's a total of 201 fields which seems like an awful lot. When a user passes another user, then 1 is added to the stats table in the rater's row for each of the passed user's attribute values, and 1 is added to the ratee's row for each of the rater's attribute values.

Each user has a stats page that shows the tally for each of the 10 possible values for each of the 10 attribute of who they passed and separately for who passed them.

My question is, is one big stats table with 201 fields the best way to set this up. I tried breaking it into two tables, one for rater and one for ratee, but the setup seemed to just add more complexity. Is there a better approach that I am not seeing to do this?

Comment: some options are listed here https://www.google.de/search?q=ruby+on+rails+track+statistics&oq=ruby+on+rails+track+statistics&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6797j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Unfortunately none of those results related to my question. They were mainly gems that track app usage statistics (e.g., how many visitors to the site, what pages they visited, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a table with 200+ columns is pretty much the worst imaginable solution.

### The classic way

The "classic" way to do this is by a creating a key/value table:

```
class CreateStats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :stats do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
      t.string :key
      t.boolean :value

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :attributes, :key
  end
end
```

Another variation of this is one is where you store the available keys in a master table to provide data normalization:

```
class CreateStats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :attributes do |t|
      t.string :key
    end
    add_index :attributes, :key
  end
end

class CreateUserStats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_stats do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :attribute, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :value

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :stats, [:key_id, :user_id]
  end
end

class Stat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_attributes
end

class UserStat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stat
  delegate :key, to: :stat
end
```

(+) Its a regular relational table so that you can use ActiveRecord associations to link UserAttributes to some kind of Rating.

```
class UserStat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stat
  has_many :stat_reviews
  delegate :key, to: :stat
end

class StatReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_stat
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: :user
end
```

(-) A column can only have a single type in a relational database. This usually means you have to use a string column and type cast values in the application.

### HSTORE, JSON and JSONB

Postgres now has additional data types such as HSTORE, JSON and JSONB that can be used to store arbitrary key/value type data structures.

(+) Untyped / schemaless so you can use any type you want for the value.

(-) Non-relational so you cannot use associations.

Comment: Thanks. I've been playing around with the JSONB datatype and got it working. That brings the stats table fields down from 201 to 21. Much more manageable. From looking at your first two options, I'm not completely sure how the counting is done. Does this add a new stats record every time a user is rated? Then I do a count on each key to collect the stats? As opposed to one record for each user where I add 1 to the appropriate attribute each time a rating is done.

Comment: No, you have a separate `StatReview` model that references `UserStat`.    To get a count of the reviews you can do something like: `UserStat.joins(:stat, :stat_reviews).select("user_stats.*, COUNT(stat_reviews.id) AS user_stats.reviews_count, stats.key AS user_stats.key").group('users_stats.id')`

Comment: You can also use a counter cache.

Comment: Thanks. For now I'll use the JSONB storage option you suggested and play around with your other suggestions at a later date. I found out those are called the Entity-Attribute-Value pattern which I didn't know about but can look into.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. Imagine the work you would have to do if you added a new attribute to be track? You'd have to write another migration.

I'd suggest using a join table to keep track of the user being evaluated, the user who is the evaluator, the stat_id, and the score. This also requires a stats table.

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class UserStatRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :evaluator, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :stat

  validates_presence_of :score
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_stat_ratings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Using this method you can create more stats down the road `Stat.create(name: 'new stat')` and not have to change your schema.